# Where to connect c wire

Tags: furnace, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

[image]

I’m installing a new WiFi thermostat that needs the c wire.  I ended up running new thermostat wires that contained the common wire but now I’m stuck on where to connect it to the furnace.

Can someone take a look at the wiring diagram to help me figure out if I have a place on my furnace to connect the c wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The AR861 doesn't provide that functionality, sorry!

Unfortunately, the AR861 does not provide a C wire from its internal transformer, so you'll have to use an external transformer on Rc and C with the supply from the AR861 connected to Rh on the thermostat.

Comment: You'll have to dig inside the furnace to find the transformer and its 24VAC wires. It's also possible the neutral side of the 24VAC is wired to the furnace's metal frame.